# OracleでデータベースキャラクタセットがJA16SJISTILDEのとき、NVARCHAR2に  を入れたい

Tags: oracle

以下のような Oracle の環境を用いて、 NVARCHAR2 に「」を入れようとしていますが、どうしてか文字化けしてしまいます。

- サーバー : Oracle Database 11.2.0.4 (64bit) (ホストOS:Windows7 64bit)
- クライアントライブラリ : Oracle.ManagedDataAccess  4.121.2.0
- クライアントPC : Windows 7 (64bit)
- データベースキャラクタセット : JA16SJISTILDE
- 各国語キャラクタセット : AL16UTF16
- NLS_LANG : JAPANESE_JAPAN.JA16SJISTILDE (Oracle ManagedDataAccess では NLS_LANG を設定できないので無関係だとは思いますが)

各国語キャラクタセットに設定されたエンコーディングで文字列を格納できると考えているのですが、データベースキャラクタセットが JA16SJISTILDE のときに、期待した結果が得られませんでした。

```
CREATE TABLE NVARCHAR_TEST (
  NAME  NVARCHAR2(32)
);
INSERT  INTO  NVARCHAR_TEST  VALUES ('田');
INSERT  INTO  NVARCHAR_TEST  VALUES (N'田');
INSERT  INTO  NVARCHAR_TEST  VALUES (UNISTR('\D842\DFB7') || '田');
```

最後の INSERT は期待する結果が得られますが、さすがに使えません。
各国語キャラクタセットはデータベースキャラクタセットから独立しているだろうと考えていたのですが、何か勘違いしているでしょうか？（データベースキャラクタセットを AL32UTF8 にすると、普通に格納できています）。

どうすれば、データベースキャラクタセットに関わらず各国語キャラクタセットのエンコードで文字列を格納できるのでしょうか。

### 編集

バインド変数を使用した場合について、INSERTしているサンプルコード。

```
using (var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
{
    var command = connection.CreateCommand();
    var parameter = command.CreateParameter();
    parameter.DbType = DbType.String;
    parameter.ParameterName = "name";
    parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    parameter.Value = "田";
    command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
    command.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO NVARCHAR_TEST VALUES (:name)";
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

これだと文字化けしてしまう。

Comment: 環境変数 `$ORA_NCHAR_LITERAL_REPLACE` は設定されてますか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。クライアントの環境変数 ORA_NCHAR_LITERAL_REPLACE に TRUE を指定したのですが、変化がないようでした。
不勉強で、この環境変数の存在を見逃していましたが、探してみたところ、

Comment: OTNのフォーラムでも同様の訴えがあるようでした。
https://community.oracle.com/thread/3987269
これは ODP.NET Oracle 管理対象ドライバ の問題かもしれませんね。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Oracle Support で問い合わせ、サンプルコードを提示したところ、OracleParameter を使用する回答を得ました。。

```
using (var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
{
    var command = connection.CreateCommand();
    var parameter = (OracleParameter)command.CreateParameter();
    //parameter.DbType = DbType.String;
    parameter.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.NChar;
    parameter.ParameterName = "name";
    parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    parameter.Value = "田";
    command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
    command.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO NVARCHAR_TEST VALUES (:name)";
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

ということで、ADO.NET のクラスでは実現できないという結論に至りました。